# NEST Fuzziness is not sending the correct JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, elasticsearch, nest

The following JSON is what I need MVC NEST to send as request:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "text": {
       "fields": "_all",            
        "query":     "monelo",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO",
        "operator":  "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the JSON that is sent instead, (the text node is missing, and it seems crucial in order to get fuzzied results back).

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
       "fields": "_all",            
        "query":     "monelo",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO",
        "operator":  "and"
    }
  }
}
```

The above JSON is generated and sent as request with:

```
var productsQuery =
client.Search<Elastic.Product>(s => s.Index(indexName).Type("products").Query(q => q.QueryString(qstr => qstr
.Fields("_all")
.Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)
.Query("*" + query + "*")))
.Size(100));
```

I debugged with Fiddler and if I add in the text node then I get the desired results.

So, I'm either not doing it right or the NEST client that I'm using is not up to date with the latest spec of Elasticsearch REST.

I've spent several hours if not a day studying the documentation and I have literally tried every query type and each property available.

Also tried using the LowLevelClient to send a request with raw json but this does not allow me to deserialize the retrieved results into multiple Elastic.Product objects.

Comment: What version of NEST are you using, and what version of Elasticsearch are you targeting?

Comment: @RussCam NEST 2.4.5 - Elasticsearch 2.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using a Bool query, with a must and should clause.

```
            var productsQuery =
                client.Search<Elastic.Product>(s => s.Index(indexName).Type("products").Query(q => q.Bool(b =>
                        b.Must(mq => mq.Fuzzy(f => f.Field("_all").Value(query.ToLower()).Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)))
                        .Should(sq => sq.QueryString(sqqs => sqqs.DefaultField("_all").Query("*" + query.ToLower() + "*")))))
                        .From(0)
                        .Size(100)
                        .Sort(ss => ss.Field(f => f.Field("displayName"))));
```